# Laravel localization in 404 page using session

Tags: php, laravel, session, http-status-code-404, locale

I set locale in middleware using session variable and it is working perfectly except 404 page. As I understood, neither session variables nor middleware works in exception handler. Here is my code:

Route:

```
    Route::get('setlocale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
  if (in_array($locale, \Config::get('app.locales'))) {
    Session::put('locale', $locale);

  }
  return redirect()->back();
})->name('lang.switch');
```

Middleware:

```
class Language
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $raw_locale = Session::get('locale');
        if (in_array($raw_locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) {
            $locale = $raw_locale;
        } else $locale = Config::get('app.locale');

        App::setLocale($locale);


        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Any ideas?